# Chrome Developer Tools not showing CSS sheet or line for locally hosted Zurb Foundation pages

Tags: google-chrome, zurb-foundation, developer-tools

This is kind of a long shot, but I'm at my wit's end. At some point in developing a locally hosted Foundation page, the Chrome Developer tools stopped displaying the stylesheet and line for each individual CSS rule when inspected, but instead just seems to show the media query for the element. I've noticed that other pages I've built with Foundation, locally hosted are doing the same thing. It only seems to be locally hosted Foundation pages that are giving me this problem. Locally hosted Bootstrap pages work as expected, as well as Foundation pages that are actually hosted. I have no idea what is going on here, or why the Developer Tools would just stop working in the middle of a build. I've checked all my settings, went as far as downloading Chrome Canary and am seeing the same results. I'm not running any kind of local server like MAMP, and this have never been an issue in the past.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `prefixfree.min.js` just remove or comment it out and everything should go back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the answer was in my file folder structure. The parent folder contained a blank " "space, replaced with a - everything seems to work.

Comment: This is happening to me too, but there are no spaces in my parent folder. I started seeing this this morning after not being in dev tools for a few days. Instead of CSS file name and line number, I'm seeing the name of the file displayed in the browser (i.e., "myfile.html").